# How can I make the security rules of my Firebase Realtime Database read cookies?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I'm working with Firebase, and recently started to look into the security rules to protect the accounts inside my Realtime Database. I went out to search for good answer, but none of them satisfy me. I now came to stack overflow community to answer my question.

I've already looked into other ways to secure my database, but none of them seem to fit what I'm trying to do. I also tried to make it so that if the domain was this, than it would allow the page to read and write to the database.

This represents the basic layout of a database similar to my user list

```
{
   "accounts": {
      "tokens": {
         "78238535": {
            "username":"test"
         }
      },
      "users": {
         "test": {
            "myData":"chocolate"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

How would I get the security rules to see a cookie called "token", and find the token under accounts/tokens, than go to accounts/users and use the username from the token it identifies with and allow read and writes to anything in the user's folder (in this case, it is named test).

I expect something similar to this to work, since it uses json and looks like javascript. The only problem is reading the cookie "token" and maybe storing it as a variable, or using it in one string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browser cookies are not available for user with Firebase security rules.  You also can't restrict accessed based on the domain of the web page that the user is using.  For the purpose of security rules, you need to assume that the user is coming from anywhere on the internet, not necessarily through a web page you create.

Comment: Aw, well would you know how to secure the data only coming from my website, not by domain because it apparently won't work. I wish these things would work.

Comment: Is their a way I can hide some code from the client screen, like hide nav.js (Or even encode it so they can't read it).

Comment: Not really.  You should assume that anyone can see the full code of any JavaScript that gets transferred to the browser.

Comment: uuuuhg, setting up security rules is so hard. Wait, when I hide a pastebin script, can I access it from my website to call functions?

Comment: Can you access it from a browser in incognito/private mode?  If so, then yes.